# Does the Spell Attack modifier apply to spell damage?

Tags: spellcasting, dnd-next-playtest

My group and I are new to D&D and we read through the rules for the D&D Next play test.  It seems to indicate that attack modifiers apply to damage as a bonus.  Does this apply with the magic modifier to spell damage?  So does 18 intelligence for a level 1 Wizard give +5 bonus damage to spells?  I don't see how the attack bonus otherwise would be relevant since it seems the opposing creatures have to make a DC check against the spells.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this playtest version question as a duplicate of the same question about the full version, so as to point people there. (I don't believe this question should be edited, and is fine as is, except for that the duplicate closure would be helpful.)

Comment: Voting to reopen. See [this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61945746#61945746), in particular my comment: "Playtest material presents certain challenges that official releases do not. Even if a next-gen question concerns material unchanged from the playtest, it is not the same question as the playtest question."

Comment: **However** a reference to the newer edition is appropriate: [5e Version](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53292/does-your-spell-modifier-add-to-your-spell-damage)

Answer (score 14):

On page 3 of Character Creation it states, that the spell casting bonus applies to two things:

- The Spell DC for the spell (you add this to your stat and 10 and get the DC)
- The attack from the spell. If the spell makes an attack you add this to the attack roll.

The melee/ranged attack modifier also only applies to the to-hit. It does not apply to the damage.