# Is there anything wrong with my character sheet?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am playing dungeon and dragons and still a very new player. I created a character and leveled it to level 2.  I am not sure if I did it correctly.

[Google Drive link for character sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7R6vObGvoW4Y3k2cHJZNFNKSm8/view?usp=sharing)

I am not sure what spell save dc or spell attack bonus is for or how it is used.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes you think it isn't leveled correctly? Are there parts of the books you aren't understanding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does your spell modifier add to your spell damage?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53292/does-your-spell-modifier-add-to-your-spell-damage)

Comment: dupe in that the linked question ^^ effectively serves, in the *question* post, as an answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to D&D! Lemme answer your question before I point out a few (small) errors on your sheet.

Spell saves are calculated by 8+CHA(because you're a sorcerer)+proficiency in this case, it should be 13. This stat is a number that enemies have to roll against to see if they are affected by your spell.

Your spell attack bonus should be CHA(Again, because sorcerers)+proficiency bonus, so it should be 5. This is added to your d20 roll when you roll to attack with a spell such as firebolt (I want to say this is the case for ray of frost and acid splash on your sheet but I can't be certain off the top of my head).

A few things to point out:

1. because you have 15 dex and daggers are finesse weapons, you can choose to use your dex instead of strength to calculate attack and damage. So attack could be a +4 and not a +1; damage could be 1d4+2 and not 1d4-1.
2. Your proficiencies are Stat+proficiency bonus, so insight should be WIS(-1)+Prof(+2) = +1 and religion should be INT(0) + Prof(+2) = 2.

Other than that, you did a great job for a newbie. Have fun in your games!

Comment: He should have two personality traits; the list of spells under "attacks and spellcasting" doesn't match the list of spells on page 2 (each has spells not on the other); and I would actually advise against identifying the sorcery points as used on the sheet proper - since they can be changed at any time as a bonus action, it's probably best to have the sheet simply say that there are 3 1st-level spell slots and 2 (unused) sorcery points, and simply announce "I'm using my sorcery points for an additional spell slot" during play. Was a Sorcerous Origin selected? If not, that should be done too.