# How much damage do I deal with the Shocking Grasp cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, cantrips

The description of the [*shocking grasp*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp) cantrip says:

> Make a melee spell attack against the target. You have advantage on
>   the attack roll if the target is wearing armor made of metal. On a
>   hit, the target takes 1d8 lightning damage, and it can’t take
>   reactions until the start of its next turn.

How much damage do I deal with *shocking grasp*? Would it do 1d8 (+ spellcasting modifier) damage? Or would it do 1d6 + (attack modifier) in addition to the 1d8 roll?

I am assuming that, as it's a cantrip, it's just the 1d8 lightning damage, but I want to check because it's unclear to me.

Comment: Incredibly related (do either of these answer your question?): "[Does your spell modifier add to your spell damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53292)" and "[How do I figure the dice and bonuses for attack rolls and damage rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72910)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### It's just 1d8 lightning damage, without any modifier

Though a "melee spell attack" [is still a melee attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112213/), it never assumes you make a melee attack *with your weapon*. Moreover, since the spell has a somatic component, you need at least one free hand to perform it.

You don't add your weapon damage to it — it deals as much damage as its description says, no less, no more. See also: [Does a Melee spell attack count as a Weapon attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158381/)

There *are* spells that include a weapon attack as part of the casting of the spell, such as the [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) or [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) cantrips (SCAG, p. 142-143). But if that's the case, its description always says this explicitly:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon

Another example is the cleric's [*inflict wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/inflict-wounds) as a point of comparison. It does not involve a weapon attack:

> Make a melee spell attack against a creature you can reach. On a hit, the target takes 3d10 necrotic damage

(thanks [@KorvinStarmast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/22566/korvinstarmast) for this suggestion)